# How to export EclipseLink objects to XML

Tags: java, xml, export, eclipselink

is there an easy approach to store my model, which I use with EclipseLink, in XML files?

I want to implement an export functionality in my program and I was wondering if this can be done with eclipselink or with any other framework.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about trying to export the data from your database, rather than through your java layer?

Comment: Thanks, but since it should be done by users and not admins or programmers, I need to implement that functionality and I am looking for some ideas elegantly doing the xml export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your data model, using [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) should be a relatively easy way to marshal (export) your objects to XML. You will have to annotate your entities with `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlType` and your fields with `@XmlElement` or `@XmlAttribute`.

Comment: The EclipseLink MOXy component is a JAXB implementation.  It also has extensions to handle JPA entities (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA )

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the EclipseLink MOXy component ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/MOXy ).  This will easily allow you to map your existing POJO's to XML.